# Encoding to base64

Tags: math, encoding, base64, decoding

The base64 string `ADEwNjcANDEzNDgxODdCNjcyNzIxMzU5NjU1M0VBM0JFOEE5QzM=` when decoded is `106741348187B6727213596553EA3BE8A9C3`. When I encode `106741348187B6727213596553EA3BE8A9C3` to base64 the result is `MTA2NzQxMzQ4MTg3QjY3MjcyMTM1OTY1NTNFQTNCRThBOUMz`.

I'm certain that the un-encoded string is the input for the first base64 string because the un-encoded string is made up of a user id and an authorization token joined. So if decoding from base64 gives me these two specific strings joined, but encoding results in something different from the string from which they were decoded, how exactly was the un-encoded string encoded to the base64 string to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the result of decoding your input isn't `106741348187B6727213596553EA3BE8A9C3`; it's `\01067\041348187B6727213596553EA3BE8A9C3`.  Note the two null bytes, which are presumably getting stripped before you re-encode it.

If you decode and re-encode without stripping those nulls, you get the input back:

```
$ echo "ADEwNjcANDEzNDgxODdCNjcyNzIxMzU5NjU1M0VBM0JFOEE5QzM=" | base64 -d | base64
ADEwNjcANDEzNDgxODdCNjcyNzIxMzU5NjU1M0VBM0JFOEE5QzM=
```

To better see what's going on, look at the actual bytes being output by your decoder:

```
$ echo "ADEwNjcANDEzNDgxODdCNjcyNzIxMzU5NjU1M0VBM0JFOEE5QzM=" | base64 -d | od -c
0000000  \0   1   0   6   7  \0   4   1   3   4   8   1   8   7   B   6
0000020   7   2   7   2   1   3   5   9   6   5   5   3   E   A   3   B
0000040   E   8   A   9   C   3
0000046
```

Comment: I suppose it isn't necessary, but I don't see the output of the decode. What is the encoder you're using there? I'm using PHP's base64_encode. Is there some reason that a well-established language like PHP should have an inadequate base64 encoding function?

Comment: Ok, so seeing the output helped. My decoding method was not showing the null byte.

Comment: Thank you. This is instructive for me since I also didn't realize bash had that functionality.